# Fastest connection between servers in Switzerland(any city) and London. Best Datacenter

Tags: connection, datacenter

I've spend 2 weeks searching best datacenter to get fastest conection beetwen Switzerland (<50ms). Is anyone know about some good DC?

Comment: this is a very, very, vauge question. For starters, speed ? latency ? reliability ? price ? customer service ? peerage ? redundancy ?   etc etc. what do you care about ? what are you willing to sacrifice ? Are you colocating or buying servers from a hoster ?

Answer (score 0):

Fast connections are all about the networking provider.  Being in a datacenter with access to many top-grade ISPs is what you'll want.  The largest carrier-neurtral data center folks in Switzerland that come to mind are:

- [Interxion](http://www.interxion.ch/)
- [ColoZüri](http://colozueri.ch/)
- [Green.ch](http://www.datacenter.green.ch/en/multi-tier-datacenter.htm)
- [Equinix](http://www.equinix.com/data-center-locations/map/data-centre-europe/)

There are plenty of ISPs in each of those vendor's data centers who can sort you out.  Level 3, Swisscom, etc.

But it sounds like you want an all-in-one package.  If you want a vendor to also provide the top-grade networking along with housing, then consider:

- [Aspectra](http://www.aspectra.ch/)
- [Netcetera](http://netcetera.ch/en/home.html)
- [Green.ch](http://www.datacenter.green.ch/en/multi-tier-datacenter.htm) (again)

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to give Colt a go (http://www.colt.net). Many datacentres Europe-wide (including London and Zurich), excellent network and very strong Managed Services division.